# ReverseArrayInPlace Strange error?

Tags: javascript, eloquent, reverse

I was reading the eloquent book, did a little assignment and ran into something that i can't really figure out. why return gives one answer and console.log gives a different one?

```
function reverseArrayInPlace(r){
 var z = [];
  for(var c = (r.length)-1;c>=0;c--){
   z.push(r[c]); 
  }
  console.log(z);
return z;
}


var arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);
console.log(arrayValue);
// → [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Result:

[5, 4, 3, 2, 1] <- console.log(z)

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] <- return z

Comment: If you really want to reverse an array in place, you could just do `arr.reverse()` ?

Comment: yes but didnt want to use it for now, just exploring. thx tho!

Answer (score 2):

You aren't reversing the array *in place*. You are creating a new array that is returned by `reverseArrayInPlace`

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

Instead of creating a new array and returning it, simply replace the contents of the original array with the one you reversed by using this line at the end of your function:

```
r.splice.apply(r,[0,r.length].concat(z))
```

This line removes all elements from array `r` and replaces them with all elements from array `z` and then you can simply return `r`

```
function reverseArrayInPlace(r){
 var z = [];
  for(var c = (r.length)-1;c>=0;c--){
   z.push(r[c]); 
  }
  console.log(z);
  r.splice.apply(r,[0,r.length].concat(z));
  return r;
}


var arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);
console.log(arrayValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

To reverse the array "in place," work on the original array rather than creating a new one:

```js
function reverseArrayInPlace(r) {
  var t, i, j;
  for(i = 0, j = r.length - 1 ; i < j ; i++, j--) {
    t= r[i];
    r[i]= r[j];
    r[j]= t;
  }
}

var arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);
console.log(arrayValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

`z` is not the same array as `arrayValue`. Inside your function you create a new array, called `z`, where you will `push` `arrayValue`'s elemenets in reversed order. Instead of that, might I suggest the following:

```
function reverseArrayInPlace(r){
    var aux;
    for(var c = 0; c < r.length / 2; c++){
        aux = r[c];
        r[c] = r[r.length - 1 - c];
        r[r.length - 1 - c] = aux; 
    }
}
```

arrays are passed by reference by default, so if you call `reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue)`, then after it is executed, `arrayValue` will be in reversed order. Note, that you are traversing only half of the array, since if you traverse the whole array, then you will switch the elements back.